# ActiveRecord giving wrong results for calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to make a calculation in ActiveRecord, although I don't have the correct data for it, so I'm practicing using some data that I do have. (that's why this example won't make very much logical sense)

Here's what I'm starting off with

```
Report.sum("p")
=> 11749577
Report.sum("c")
=> 2534695
```

Therefore, the sum should be `14284272`.

However, I later go on with

```
Report.sum("p+c")
=> 7976209
```

Of course, I would never actually do this sum, but I'm later going to need to do it with multiplication. I've tried this all kinds of ways (with spaces, using `calculate`, etc.), but I always seem to get the wrong answer.

Further, summing the subtraction also gives an equally strange answer:

```
Report.sum("p-c")
=> 2906819
```

Also, I know I should be using symbols when doing the sum over one variable, but it gives the same result.

By the way, I'm using PostgreSQL.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Please show the data you're working with.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the sum method?

Comment: The problem isn't `activerecord`. It is most likely your `sum` method. No one can help without seeing that method.

Comment: @Jerry @jkeuhlen `sum` is defined by `ActiveRecord`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're using a smallint for these columns and overflowing the size of smallint when you do a sum (or something along these lines).

To troubleshoot, ActiveRecord is just using sql to get this result.  Look at the end of your development.log file and you'll see that the sql generated is something like `SELECT SUM(p+c) AS sum_id FROM reports`.  If you run that same query directly against the database, do you get the same result?

Comment: Agreed; running each of the above queries with `.to_sql` on the end will tell you what query Rails is actually running; running those queries against the database will tell you if this is a Rails issue or a Postgres issue.

Comment: Yes, I do. I suppose therefore it must be a postgres problem. Both p and c are of type `integer`, which I believe should be big enough to handle the result. Further, when I do `SELECT SUM(p*c) AS sum_id FROM reports`, I get `ERROR: integer out of range`, so that was not the issue. As it turns out, the issue was that many p's and c's were NULL, so p+c would sometimes result in NULL even if not both were NULL. To solve this, I will use coalescing. Thank you for your help!